# Understanding free slip boundary condition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

In fluid dynamics, free slip boundary condition is equivalent to absence of tangential shear stress along the boundary. But then, in what sense is the word "free" used here? Does it mean that the tangential velocity can be anything?

Comment: Yes.  This is correct, given that the zero tangential shear stress constrains the tangential velocity derivative normal to the boundary as being zero.

Answer (score 5):

The no-slip boundary condition says that at the interface between a moving fluid and a stationary wall, both the normal and tangential components of the fluid velocity field are equal to zero.

On the other hand, the free-slip boundary condition says that at the interface between a moving fluid and a stationary wall, the normal component of the fluid velocity field is equal to zero, but the tangential component is unrestricted.  This condition is also sometimes called the no-penetration condition, for obvious reasons.

Comment: No-slip b.c. means the velocity of a fluid particle and a wall is the same.
The velocity can be zero or not.
So, the word 'stationary' is not precise enough.